# Visualforce: Pagination - The next, previous etc links freeze up after clicking for a while

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I implemented pagination on my visual force page looking at these two resources.
http://hisrinu.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/pagination-using-standardsetcontroller/
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/07/14/visualforce-page-with-pagination/

My visualforce page accepts date parameters and runs a search on custom object records and displays them in an Apex:datatable.

Here is my controller code. This works fine until I begin click the next, previous links continuously for about a minute and then it begins to slow down and freeze up.

Any idea why this is happening?

**UPDATE: 7/28: This is happening only in IE. I have IE 9.**

```
    public with sharing class FundingReportController { 

  // the soql without the order and limit
  private String soql {get;set;}

  Public Integer size{get;set;}
  Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;} 


  //export to excel - returns a page reference to the AccountDataExcel page
    public PageReference exportToExcel() {
      return Page.fundingreportExcel;
    }

    //Instantiate the StandardSetController
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController con{get; set;}






   public List<Money_Transaction__c> moneyTransactions
    {
        get
        {
            if(con != null)
                return (List<Money_Transaction__c>)con.getRecords();
            else
                return null ;
        }
        set;
    }  


 // returns a list of wrapper objects for the sObjects in the current page set
    public List<Money_Transaction__c> getMoneyTransactions() {
    try{
        //moneyTransactions = new List<MoneyTransactionWrapper>();
        moneyTransactions = new List<Money_Transaction__c>();
        for (Money_Transaction__c mt: (List<Money_Transaction__c>)con.getRecords()) 
         {              
            moneyTransactions.add(mt); 
         }       

        }
          catch (Exception e) 
            {
               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Code Error '+e));
            }
        return moneyTransactions ;
    }

  // the current sort direction. defaults to asc
  public String sortDir {
    get  { if (sortDir == null) {  sortDir = 'asc'; } return sortDir;  }
    set;
  }

  // the current field to sort by. defaults to last name
  public String sortField {
    get  { if (sortField == null) {sortField = 'Settlement_Date_First__c'; } return sortField;  }
    set;
  }

  // format the soql for display on the visualforce page
  public String debugSoql {
    //get { return soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 20'; }
    get { return soql + ' ' + sortDir; }
    set;
  }

  // init the controller and display some sample data when the page loads
  public FundingReportController() {

    moneyTransactions = new List<Money_Transaction__c>();
    //Default dates: 6 months before today
    Date fromDate = date.today();
    fromDate = fromDate.addMonths(-6);
    String fromDateStr = String.ValueOf(fromDate);
    //ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,fromDateStr   ));
    //Default dates: Today
    Date toDate = date.today();    
    String toDateStr = String.ValueOf(toDate);




     soql = 'select ACH_Type__c, Settlement_Date_First__c, Total_ACH_Amount__c,Settlement__r.id,Settlement__r.name,Money_Movement_Type__c,Bank_Name__c,Bank_Account_Number__c,Tax_Batch__c,Payroll_Group_Detail__c from Money_Transaction__c where Settlement_Date_First__c <= '+ toDateStr + ' AND Settlement_Date_First__c >= ' + fromDateStr + ' AND ACH_Type__c != \'VHR DDP Disbursement\'';


     runQuery();
  }

  // toggles the sorting of query from asc<-->desc
  public void toggleSort() {
  //ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Inside Toggle'+soql + sortField +sortDir ));
    // simply toggle the direction
    sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    // run the query again
    runQuery();
  }

  // runs the actual query
  public void runQuery() {

    try {


          size=10;  

          ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Inside New Run query + StandardSetController '+soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir));
          con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 100'));
          // sets the number of records in each page set
          con.setPageSize(size);
          noOfRecords = con.getResultSize();       



    } catch (Exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Ooops! SOQL error '+soql ));
    }

  }

  // runs the search with parameters passed via Javascript
  public PageReference runSearch() {

    String fromDate = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fromDate');
    String toDate = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('toDate');




    soql = 'select ACH_Type__c, Settlement_Date_First__c, Total_ACH_Amount__c,Settlement__r.id,Settlement__r.name,Money_Movement_Type__c,Bank_Name__c,Bank_Account_Number__c,Tax_Batch__c,Payroll_Group_Detail__c from Money_Transaction__c where Settlement_Date_First__c <= '+ toDate + ' AND Settlement_Date_First__c >= ' + fromDate + ' AND ACH_Type__c != \'VHR DDP Disbursement\'';
    con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(soql)); 


    // run the query again
    runQuery();

    return null;
  }


    // indicates whether there are more records after the current page set.
    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return con.getHasNext();

        }
        set;
    }

    // indicates whether there are more records before the current page set.
    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return con.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }

    // returns the page number of the current page set
    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return con.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }

    // returns the first page of records
    public void first() { 

        try{
        con.first();  


        }
        catch (Exception e) 
            {
               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Code Error '+e));
            }

    }

    // returns the last page of records
    public void last() {   

        try{
        con.last();        

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
            {
               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Code Error '+e));
            }
    }

    // returns the previous page of records
    public void previous() {   

         try{
            con.previous();      

            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Code Error '+e));
            }
        }

    // returns the next page of records
    public void next() {  
    try{   

        con.next();      

        }
         catch (Exception e) 
            {
               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Code Error '+e));
            }

    }       




}
```

Comment: If this is happening consistently I'd recommend getting support on this.  Note you'll have to push like hell to get it up to Tier 3 / R&D before you'll get anything approaching a useful answer.  Unless you have premier support, Salesforce first line responders are dumb as bricks.

Comment: Looks like I will have to open a ticket with Salesforce now as this is a bug which happens only with IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project was stalled for some months. I returned to it and this time I used SOQL with the new OFFSET feature and got rid of the standardcontroller.

The actual issue was IE9 itself and I have posted the details and the solution here. 
I hope it helps someone with the same re-rendering issues with IE9 and Visualforce.

Thanks.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7917/visualforce-major-grief-with-ie9-ajax-refresh-rerender-issues

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a lot going on, but for starters:

Your instantiating the standardsetcontroller twice in the same operation:

```
PageReference runsearch(){
   ...
   con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(soql)); 
   ..
   runQuery();
}

void runQuery(){
   ...
   con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 100'));
   ...
}
```

Try making a single instance of the standard set controller and instantiating it once. Than reset the `Database.querylocator(soql)` if you need to update the results for subsequent operations. Although pagination probably isn't one of the, as it's typically used for that.

That could be the begging of your issue, are you using the system debugger? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: hey Jordan thanks I will look into making those corrections. One more thing to add, this is happening only in IE!!!!! When I tried this in Chrome it worked fine. :(

Comment: It could be a bloated view state. RichardN, can you verify with the view state inspector?

Comment: It is not due to bloated viewstate based on the inspector view but what are the best practices around this and how to avoid viewstate bloating?